# Java Mysql Update Statement

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am trying to update mysql record using Java Swing. Seems like there is some problem with MySql Update statement.  I have pasted the code as under:

```
conDBase = getConnection();
stmt = conDBase.createStatement();

String sql = "update user set role = " + jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+  "where userID =" +  jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();

stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
conDBase.close();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Role Updated");
this.dispose();
new Admin().setVisible(true);
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: You can't update MySQL rows using Java Swing.

Answer (score 6):

Well, there are at least two problems with your code:

- You're not using a prepared statement, which means you've left yourself open for SQL injection. (You're not even quoting the values you *are* using, which could potentially count as a third problem.)
- You don't have a space before the "where" clause

I suspect it's the latter problem which you're noticing *right now*, but you should *definitely* fix the code to use prepared statements as well.

Oh, and you probably shouldn't be doing any of this on the UI thread (or accessing the UI controls from a non-UI thread) either...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what error message you are getting (perhaps you could post some details up).

However, the following line needs to be altered:

```
String sql = "update user set role = " + jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+  " where userID =" +  jComboBox2.getSelectedItem() + ";";
```

Notice the space before the "where" and the semi-colon at the end of the statement.

A better version would look like:

```
public int updateRoleForUser (String role, Integer userId) throws Exception {

int i = 0;

String sql =
            " update user "
            + " set role = ?"
            + " where userId = ?;";

    try {
        conDBase = getConnection();
        ps = conDBase.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, role);
        ps.setInt(2, userId);

        i = ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do something with Exception here. Maybe just throw it up again
    } finally {
        closeConnection();
        return i;
    }
};
```

Then call the method using the values from your Combo Boxes.

You should really put the whole lot into a method within a DAO class of some description and then pass in the role and userId values as parameters;

Answer (score 1):

You must put an space between the quote and the "where". Like this:

```
...getSelectedItem() + " where...
```

because, if not, you'll get something like:

```
...set role = 25where userId...
```